# ERROR: Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) Arrays?

Tags: c++, sorting

Every time i run the program I receive the message:  Segmentation fault (core dumped). I tried doing a bit of research and it seems the issue has to do with allocating to illegal memory. I've also tried debugging the program and it seems the problem lies with in the linearsort() function since after commenting it out, the rest of the statements work correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    void linearsort(int [], int);

    int arr[10];
    for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        arr[j] = j +1;

    linearsort(arr,10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;



}

void linearsort(int arr[],int n)
{
    int temp;

    for(int pass = 0; pass < n - 1; n++)
        for(int cand = pass + 1; cand < n; cand++){
            if(arr[pass] > arr[cand]){
                temp = arr[pass];
                arr[pass] = arr[cand];
                arr[cand] = temp;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `n++` should be `pass++`

Comment: For such things, you could debug yourself. It's much more rewarding to find the bug by yourself than by asking for help. One or two `cout << ... << endl` thrown in `linearsort`, or a debugging session (e.g. with gdb) and you would have found the problem pretty easily. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(int pass = 0; pass < n - 1; n++)
```

You are incrementing the wrong value, `n++` should be `pass++`. Meaning right now, you're accessing out of bound indices in your array.

Comment: Figured it out 10 seconds after you. Damn ninjas. :)

Comment: @Pikrass Thrill of the race ;)